# Accessing mounted volumes from docker for composer/npm installs on build time?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php, dockerfile

I'm looking for a better solution to install composer or npm packages inside of host volumes mounted via docker-compose.

In my docker-compose.yml, I have:

```
volumes:
  - ./app:/var/www/app
  ...
```

And in my dockerfile, I would want to use this volume to install stuff:

```
VOLUME ["/var/www/app"]
RUN composer install -d /var/www/app
```

But as I understand it, the volumes mounted in docker-compose are not yet available when the container is being built from the dockerfile.

So my next attempt was doing it when the container is started:

```
CMD bash -c "composer install -d /var/www/app && /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND"
```

That worked at least, but it called the composer install everytime the container was run which is redundant.

So my current idea is to use a dedicated composer image, mounting composer.json into it to install, then copy the finished vendor from the composer container somewhere into the container and link where it is needed. Like this:

```
FROM composer as composer
COPY ./app/composer.json /app
COPY ./app/composer.lock /app
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts

FROM library/ubuntu:jessie
# ... do other stuff with the main image ...

COPY --from=composer /app/vendor /var/www/composer/vendor
CMD bash -c "ln -s /var/www/composer/vendor /var/www/app/vendor  && /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND"
```

But it still feels kinda workaround-ish for such an ordinary problem. Is there a better way to go about this or any known good-practice?

Comment: Personally I prefer to just execute the composer command either directly on the host or through a `exec` or `run` via docker. And only do that when it is actually required.

Comment: I also did that, but then you are required to pollute your host system with all the toolkits and whatnot. Say you develop for different versions, it's gonna be utter chaos. And if you exec it, you have to do it every single time you rebuild a container, and that would also limit automation possibilities for testing... :/

Answer (score 3):

What I consider best practice, and what I do professionally, is to not use volumes at all for this case.  My Dockerfile `COPY`s in the application code at build time.  I have a working host development setup (the only real host dependency is Node itself; everything else is in the `node_modules` directory) and so if I have an issue I can reproduce, debug, and write a test for it in my local environment.  Only when that works do I go back to Docker.

```
FROM ???
WORKDIR /var/www/app
COPY app/composer.json app/composer.lock ./
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts
COPY app/ ./
...
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

Otherwise, there's a couple of things about Docker volumes to remember here:

- Everything in the Dockerfile happens before any volumes or environment variables in the `docker-compose.yml` file are even considered.  If your goal is to populate a volume, you can't do it in the Dockerfile (and this is just awkward in Docker in general; use native host tools instead).
- If you mount a volume into a container directory, it totally hides what's there already.  I see a lot of questions with Dockerfiles that do work only inside a container-local `/app` directory, then bind-mount the local source tree over that; that basically makes the Dockerfile a no-op.
- If you have a `VOLUME` directive in your Dockerfile, you can't make any changes to that directory in the image any more.  (In your question, running `composer` after the `VOLUME` directive will silently have no effect.)
- You can mount a volume into any directory in a container regardless of whether or not it was declared as a `VOLUME`.  I'd recommend never declaring `VOLUME`s in Dockerfiles, and especially not for directories that contain code (you *want* these to be updated with new image code when a container gets deleted and recreated).

Comment: Thank you for yor detailed answer. So you're developing on your host and -at some point- you build your container with that fixed state. My "goal" is to isolate host tools regarding requirements to run my applications away from my host into the containers while still being able to make extensive code changes for ongoing development.

Comment: When I see such answers I' always very surprised - how do you actually develop if you don't use volumes? You started container, you see a typo - and in order to see it live you have to recreate the container after making a fix. With volumes you'd see it instantly. Isn't it 100500 times more efficient???

Comment: I don't use Docker at all during my day-to-day development, even if it's a key part of ultimately deploying.  Node is strictly easier to install than Docker, and I don't need to do any magic configuration to get my IDE to recognize that the interpreter is there.